# How does should an orchestration saga behave if one of the services errors out for some reason

Tags: nservicebus

I've been trying to figure this out for a while but just can't wrap my mind around it.

When a request is made to let's say service-A(also implemented using nservicebus with primary and delayed retries), and service A fails due to a transient/semi-transient error, the service retries till all retries are exhausted and the message is sent to the error queue(assuming we are using ASB or rabbitmq or maybe msmq), how should the saga behave in a scenario where the response from service A decides whether the saga made a request to service B or C. 
Or should the saga timeout if it does not receive the expected response within the set time and then proceed by making compensation requests for any other service that executed before service-A (if they need to be compensated).. or should I implement custom error handling in each service to handle transient/semi-transient errors and let the saga know if a failure has occurred(if this is the way to go about it ..how can I make use of the default nservicebus retries).....Please suggest ...

Answer (score 1):

Reply from the service would be the last step, meaning all the other steps (potentially resulting a failure) have passed. If/Once the orchestrating saga receives the reply message, it knows for a fact that the service has performed its job.

In the saga you have:

```
public class MySaga : IAmStartedBy<SagaStart>, IHandleMessage<OperationPerformed>
{
    //You'll need to map/store some sort of a ID to know the replies
    //that come back are related to which saga instance

    public Task Handle(SagaStart startMessage, IMessageContext context) 
    {
        await context.Send(new PerformOperation() 
        {
           OperationId = startMessage.Id
        });
    }

    public Task Handle(OperationPerformed message, IMessageContext context) 
    {
        //Operation has succeeded.
        //Maybe saga is finished at this point?
        MarkAsComplete();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class OperationService : IHandleMessages<PerformOperation>
{
    public async Task Handle(OperationPerformed message, IMessageContext context)
    {
        //call external service
        await httpClient.PerformNetworkBoundCall(); // <- Could fail

        await context.Reply(new OperationPerformed()
        {
            OperationId = message.OperationId
        });
    }
}
```

Now, things may get more interesting when you have more than just one service and need to wait for all of them to be finish to perform the next step (or to finish). Remember that messages or replies could come out of order, which is really where Sagas shine.

Comment: Hi Hadi, If the httpClient.PerformNetworkBoundCall() keeps failing the OperationService keeps retrying and the message is pushed to the error queue. Because of this the service will never be able to reply to the saga.

Comment: That is exactly the point! If the service call is 'transient' it will eventually success. If it is due to a bug, you'll need to fix that, deploy and retry the message to succeed. In both cases, the business scenario is not complete until the service is successfully called. You can also use Timeout mechanism as a 'compensation', e.g. if the saga process is not finished in x minutes, send a notification to the user (or whatever makes sense).

Comment: Hi Hadi, Thank you for the answer. Will go with the additional timeout option of setting timeouts for making compensation requests just in case a db failure does not recover(worst case scenario for an error that is supposed to be transient). Cheers.